# Can Eclipse/IntelliJ Idea be used to execute code on the cluster

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, intellij-idea, hortonworks-data-platform

Production system : HDP-2.5.0.0 using Ambari 2.4.0.1

Aplenty demands coming in for executing a range of code(Java MR etc., Scala, Spark, R) atop the HDP but from a desktop Windows machine IDE.

For Spark and R, we have R-Studio set-up.

The challenge lies with Java, Scala and so on, also, people use a range of IDEs from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea.

I am aware that the Eclipse Hadoop plugin is NOT actively maintained and also has aplenty bugs when working with latest versions of Hadoop, IntelliJ Idea I couldn't find reliable inputs from the official website.

I believe the Hive and HBase client API is a reliable way to connect from Eclipse etc. but I am skeptical about executing MR or other custom Java/Scala code.

I referred several threads like [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/43269/intellij-eclipse-usage-against-hdp-25-sandbox.html) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/31077/how-to-setup-intellij-idea-16-to-run-hortonworks-s.html), however, I still have the question that is any IDE like Eclipse/Intellij Idea having an official support for Hadoop ? Even the [Spring Data for Hadoop](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop) seems to lost traction, it anyways didn't work as expected 2 years ago ;)

As a realistic alternative, which tool/plugin/library should be used to test the MR and other Java/Scala code 'locally' i.e on the desktop machine using a standalone version of the cluster ?

Note : I do not wish to work against/in the sandbox, its about connecting to the prod. cluster directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a genereal solution which would work for all Hadoop services equally. Each solution has it's own development, testing and deployment scenarios as they are different standalone products. For MR case you can use **[MRUnit](https://mrunit.apache.org/)** to simulate your work locally from IDE. Another option is **[LocalJobRunner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/LocalJobRunner.html)**. They both allow you to check your MR logic directly from IDE. For Storm you can use **backtype.storm.Testing** library to simalate topology's workflow. But they all are used from IDE without direct cluster communications like in case wuth Spark and RStudio integration.

As for the MR recommendation your job should ideally pass the following lifecycle - writing the job and testing it locally, using MRUnit, then you should run it on some development cluster with some test data (see [MiniCluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html) as an option) and then running in on real cluster with some custom counters which would help you to locate your malformed data and to properly maintaine the job.